# Stuck in login loop after installing AMD graphics driver

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, login, amd-graphics

Installed AMD graphics driver form [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx).
But after reboot, I am unable to login. It keeps comming back to login screen when I type password and hit enter. I can't even login to guest user.

I have tried every thing form this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) but nothing worked for me.
I have tried this

```
chown username:username .Xauthority  
sudo chmod a+wt /tmp
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
sudo service lightdm restart
```

File also .**profile** seems fine.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Linux Kernel version 4.xx

Please suggest what to do as I can't get my work done without Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the graphics adapter?

Comment: AMD Radeon R7. Is this you are looking for or you are asking for something else?

Comment: You need to be more specific than R7. Only some R7 GPUs are supported by the _amdgpu_ driver.

Comment: @dobey AMD Radeon R7 M265. Is there any command to show more details than this or this is sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GPU is not supported by the *amdgpu* driver. You should uninstall the driver you installed from AMD.

You need to either use the open source *radeon* driver included with Ubuntu, or downgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 (no newer than the 14.04.4 point release) and use the *fglrx* proprietary driver if you need to use it rather than the open source *radeon* driver.

Comment: How did you check if my GPU is not supported by amdgpu driver? How do I uninstall the driver as i can't find this script amdgpu-pro-uninstall in /tmp/amdgpu-pro-driver? any link to radeon driver included with ubuntu?

Comment: The page on AMD's site which links to the various download pages shows you what cards are and are not supported by the different drivers. The _radeon_ driver is included by default in Ubuntu. It's what your laptop would have been using before you installed the _amdgpu-pro_ stuff. You will need to probably unpack the package again and then run the uninstall script. As /tmp is a memory backed filesystem, it is emptied at every reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove the drivers that you have installed since they are not compatible.
In the tty screen <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> login and uninstall the default graphics on your device:

```
amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```

reboot your system and use the open source *radeon* driver for a temporary fix.

---

follow this for a permanent fix:
https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx

if the problem still persists, your graphic card might be damaged.

Comment: You have to change directories first to the directory that contains amdgpu-pro-uninstall. Source: [How-To Install/Uninstall AMD Radeon Software AMDGPU-PRO Driver for Linux on an Ubuntu System](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx)